# Consuming an API via Retrofit library in Android

Tags: android, rest, api, retrofit2

I'm having an issue with implementing retrofit library on my Android Studio project. I have an API made on Ruby on Rails and the android app calling it through HTTP methods. The problem is, when I open the app it shuts down showing the error "Unfortunately, the app has stopped"
Since the code is showing no errors, I believe it's about the component's versions in Gradle
This is the gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.leandro.retrofit"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

I will leave the code of the app below, just in case

ArticleActivity Java Class

```
public class ArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000/";
    List<Article> listaArticles = new ArrayList<>();
    ArticleAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView rvClientes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rvClientes.setLayoutManager(llm);

        adapter =  new ArticleAdapter(listaArticles);
        rvClientes.setAdapter(adapter);

        DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(rvClientes.getContext(),llm.getOrientation());
        rvClientes.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        ArticleService articleService = retrofit.create(ArticleService.class);

        Call<List<Article>> lista = articleService.getArticles();
        lista.enqueue(new Callback<List<Article>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Article>> call, Response<List<Article>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                listaArticles = response.body();
                adapter = new ArticleAdapter(listaArticles);
                rvClientes.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Article>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

ArticleAdapter

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ArticleViewHolder> {

    List<Article> lista;


    public ArticleAdapter(List<Article> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.article_row,parent,false);
        return new ArticleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindArticle(lista.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    public class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvNombre;
        TextView tvId;



        public ArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvNombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvArticle);
            tvId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvID);

        }

        public void bindArticle(Article article) {
            String nombre = article.getTitle() + ":";
            tvNombre.setText(nombre);
            tvId.setText(String.valueOf(article.getId()));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting RecyclerView adapter without initializing RecyclerView object `rvClientes`.

Just initialize RecyclerView object after `setContentView()` method inside `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);

    rvClientes = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RV_ID_DEFINED_IN_LAYOUT_XML_FILE);  // change this ID

    // rest of the code
}
```

Change RecyclerView ID in `findViewById()`

Comment: Now it didn't stop working, but It's showing a blank screen without data inside. I debugged the application and the list ListaArticles size is 0. Also, I checked the url with postman and it's working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You're using `localhost` in base url. Check your system's IP address in CMD using `ipconfig` and set the same IP address in your code. An example `192.168.1.10:3000`.  That's it.

Comment: You can accept my answer as your problem resolved. And about the API request you can ask new question with [mcve] of server and client part. If not me, other fellow StackOverflow users can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am illustrate the example of fetching data from API and show in recycleView using retrofit.

first of all add dependencies for using retrofit and gson converter. Also i have used okhttp for logging.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Then make APIInterface for endpoint.

```
public interface ApiInterface {


// For POST request

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/login")
Call<responsePojo> login(@Field("user_master_id") String user_id,
                         @Field("page") String pwd);


//user_email and user_pass are the post parameters and SignUpResponse is a POJO class which recieves the response of this API


// for GET request
@GET("api/users")
// specify the sub url for our base url
Call<responsePojo> getResponse();

}
```

Then Make APIRequest Class for defining API

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiRequest {

    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private String baseURL = "https://reqres.in/";
    public String _Key = "ba167ab7f60b864976a072d53e3c41e2";

    public ApiRequest(final String token) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        // set your desired log level
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
        builder.addInterceptor(logging);
        builder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request;
                if (token != null)
                    request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("key", _Key).addHeader("token", token).build();
                else
                    request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("key", _Key).build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        String url = baseURL;

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();

        apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }


    public void getData(final ResponseCallback callBack) {
        try {
            Call<responsePojo> requestCall = apiInterface.getResponse();

            requestCall.enqueue(new Callback<responsePojo>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<responsePojo> call, Response<responsePojo> response) {
                    callBack.ResponseSuccessCallBack(response.body());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<responsePojo> call, Throwable t) {
                    callBack.ResponseFailCallBack(t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }

      }
```

You also need to add responseCallback class

```
public interface ResponseCallback {
    public void ResponseSuccessCallBack(Object object);
    public void ResponseFailCallBack(Object object);
}
```

I am posting POJO class according to my example
**ResponsePojo**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class responsePojo {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private int page;
    @SerializedName("per_page")
    @Expose
    private int perPage;
    @SerializedName("total")
    @Expose
    private int total;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    private int totalPages;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<dataPojo> data = null;

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public int getPerPage() {
        return perPage;
    }

    public void setPerPage(int perPage) {
        this.perPage = perPage;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    public void setTotalPages(int totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

    public List<dataPojo> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<dataPojo> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


}
```

**dataPojo**

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class dataPojo {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @Expose
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    @Expose
    private String lastName;
    @SerializedName("avatar")
    @Expose
    private String avatar;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

}
```

**AdapterClass**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    Activity context;
    List<dataPojo> dataPojoArrayList;

    public DataAdapter(Activity act) {
        context = act;
        dataPojoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addItem(List<dataPojo> dataPojos) {
        dataPojoArrayList.addAll(dataPojos);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        MyViewHolder v = new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_data, parent, false));
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        dataPojo s = getItem(position);

        holder.tvFirst.setText(s.getFirstName());
        holder.tvLast.setText(s.getLastName());
        holder.tvEmail.setText(s.getEmail());

        if (s.getAvatar() != null && !s.getAvatar().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(s.getAvatar())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(holder.ivAvatar);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(holder.ivAvatar);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataPojoArrayList.size();
    }

    public dataPojo getItem(int position) {
        return dataPojoArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvFirst, tvLast, tvEmail;
        private ImageView ivAvatar;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvFirst = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
            tvLast = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLastName);
            tvEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
            ivAvatar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivAvatar);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        dataPojo bean = dataPojoArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                        Toast.makeText(context, bean.getFirstName() + " " + bean.getLastName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
 private void init() {

        rvData = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvData);

        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(activity);
        rvData.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        rvData.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rvData.setClipToPadding(false);

        getUserData();

    }

    private void getUserData() {
        ApiRequest apiRequest = new ApiRequest(null);
        apiRequest.getData(callBack);
    }

    private ResponseCallback callBack = new ResponseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void ResponseSuccessCallBack(Object object) {
            try {
                if (object instanceof responsePojo) {
                    responsePojo response = (responsePojo) object;
                    if (1 == 1) {
                        try {
                            dataAdapter.addItem(response.getData());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Utils.showAlert(activity, getString(R.string.app_name), "" + response.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void ResponseFailCallBack(Object object) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```